# jQuery UI draggable not sticking to grid after scroll

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, draggable

I'm using jQuery UI's draggable functionality using a set `grid` option. My grid is set to use `[x: 130, y: 110]` constraints, and the container for the grid is a certain height that overflows its own parent, allowing me to scroll. When I have a draggable element, and I start dragging it, and scroll a bit down in the container (while still hanging on to the draggable element), the element no longer sticks to the grid.

I have made a barebone example that shows the error: [You can see the error in action in the JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lns6erm/) - try start dragging, and scroll in the container. If this is not enough of an explanation; see the GIF of the error [here](http://i.gyazo.com/b8fd4210480f1cc8a92f6e548e0a1295.gif) (it should stay in the top left corner of the grids).

I have tried changing the grid to a `[x: 100, y: 100]` and this makes it work in Chrome and Opera because they scroll by exactly 100 pixels on each scroll, but not Firefox and IE since they use soft-scroll. I have also tried "hacking" my way through it, and moving the element to the center of the nearest grid when dragging is done via jQuery UI's `droppable`, but this did not seem like it could be a usable solution.

Is there a way to ensure that the draggable element will continue to stick to the grid even if you scroll down while dragging it?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I did not :( I ended up not using a visible grid and limiting the height of the areas I needed elements to be draggable in to a height that would not allow scrolling.

Comment: Yes - for now, I have disabled scrolling whilst dragging.  The user has to "drop" the div, scroll on, and drag again..!

Oh well..

Answer (score 0):

A small hack on the code and Its working fine.

I have modified the code with small hack, added last div as **draggable** element, which will always snap to the parent (overflowContainer) in your case, even if we scroll the container.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      containment: '.overflowContainer',
      grid:[100,100],
      refreshPositions: true,      
      scroll: false,
      snap:".innerContent"
   });
```

Check complete solution under:
https://jsfiddle.net/mayankN/o7ke0pLu/3/

Answer (score 0):

It's work using set `scrollSensitivity` and `scrollSpeed` options.

I have also changed class `.overflowContainer`

Please Check below.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".dragItem").draggable({
        grid: [130, 110],
        scroll: true,
        scrollSensitivity: 100,
        scrollSpeed: 100,
    }); 
});
```

```css
.overflowContainer {
    width: 600px; 
    height: 500px;
}

.left {
    float: left; 
}

.grid {
     width: 128px; 
    height: 108px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

.dragcontainer {
position:absolute; 
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
}

.dragItem {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="overflowContainer">
    <div class="left">
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="left grid">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="dragcontainer">
    <div class="dragItem">
        Drag me
    </div>
</div>
```